# How to delete data in custom finder method in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

I want to delete data in custom finder method.

[Custom finder method document](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)

#### My code:

```
public function findPREACTIVE(Query $query, array $options) {
    $query->delete()
            ->where(['member_status' => -1])
            ->andWhere(['registered >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR)'])->execute();

    return $query
                    ->where(['email' => $options['email'], 'token_key' => $options['token_key']])
                    ->andWhere(['member_status' => -1])
                    ->andWhere(['registered < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR)']);
}
```

When i call this finder, i get error:

`You cannot call all() on a non-select query. Use execute() instead.`

Is there have solution for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to issue a separate query. What you are doing there will mess up the finder query, which is ment to be a select query.

```
$this
    ->query()
    ->delete()
    ->where(['member_status' => -1])
    ->andWhere(['registered >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 72 HOUR)'])->execute();
```

Use `applyOptions()` in case you need the finder options to be applied to the delete query too.

```
$this
    ->query()
    ->delete()
    ->applyOptions($options)
    // ...
```

Comment: Thanks you.
I did create a shell to run separate task.